# TSQL Is returning boolean is not possible?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can't i write something in TSQL

```
declare @set1 int
declare @set2 int
set @set1=1
set @set2=2

select @set1 < @set2
```

by getting true as result?

I Know i can use

```
case when @set<@set then 'true'
```

but can't i do by the way i have written above?

Comment: Yet another reason that SQL isn't a real language.

Answer (score 2):

No; `T-SQL` does not treat boolean expressions as data. In the same way, you couldn't assign a boolean expression directly to a `bit` field.

Comment: @gbn: Maybe I wasn't clear: I'm saying that you cannot assign a *boolean expression* to a `bit` column. That is, this isn't legal: `update MyTable set BitColumn = @param1 < @param2`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has no "implied" type that would be boolean from an expression. In reality it could be any type to SQL server and it's arguably convention that says an expression is boolean in .net.

It has a bit data type that is almost like boolean and maps directly to boolean in client code and accepts true or false as strings.

```
DECLARE @foo bit
SET @foo = 'true' -- = 1
```